# Add class to div depending on class in another div

Tags: html, css

I have a situation that looks something like this:

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="is-active">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <div>Text 1</div>
  <div>Text 2</div>
  <div>Text 3</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 40px;
  
  > div {
    text-align: center;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      background: rgba(red, 0.5);
      
      &.is-active {
        background: rgba(red, 1.0);
      }
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: rgba(green, 0.5);
      
      &.is-active {
        background: rgba(green, 1.0);
      }
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      background: rgba(blue, 0.5);
      
      &.is-active {
        background: rgba(blue, 1.0);
      }
    }

    &:nth-child(4) {
      background: rgba(yellow, 0.5);
      
      &.is-active {
        background: rgba(yellow, 1.0);
      }
    }
  }
}

.bottom {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
  
  > div {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9yeLcvow/

Now, right now it's just static, i.e. I have manually given the first `div` of the top container the class `is-active`. When a `div` has this class, the opacity should change from 0.5 to 1. However, what I would also like to do is change the color of the `bottom` container to match the color of the `is-active` div in the top container.

Can this be done somehow, without using JS ?

Comment: No, you can't, This would require going UP the Dom before going down with your selector.

Comment: Can it be done with JS then ?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first element with the `is-active` class with `document.querySelector`, then get its computed color and assign it to the color style property of the element with the class `bottom`:

```js
document.querySelector('.bottom').style.color = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.is-active')).getPropertyValue("color");
```

```css
.is-active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="is-active">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <div>Text 1</div>
  <div>Text 2</div>
  <div>Text 3</div>
</div>
```